# SQL to return integer values not used within a particular range

Tags: sql, select

Is it possible to use SQL to return a list of values that are NOT in a particular dataset but are within the range of values?

For example, I have a column with the following....

```
Registration_no
1
5
6
9
```

I would like to return all the 'unused' integers between the min and the max in the range, which in this example would 2, 3, 4, 7 and 8

Is this possible by way of a SQL statement?

Many thanks,

Comment: SELECT * FROM $table WHERE Registration_no  BETWEEN $lownumber AND $highnumber

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It's an Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get them as a list of values using generic SQL.  But, you can get them as ranges.

```
select registration_no + 1 as StartMissingRange, registration_no - 1 as EndMissingRange
from (select r.*,
             (select min(registration_no)
              from registrations r2
              where r2.registration_no > r.registration_no
             ) as next_ro
      from registrations r
     ) t
where next_ro <> registration_no + 1;
```

This is generic SQL.  There are other solutions depending on the database (such as using `lead()` function).  If you want the list with separate numbers on each row, then a recursive CTE is one method supported by many databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [table]
(number varchar(250))

INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (1),(5),(6),(9)

SELECT * FROM [table]

DEClARE @a varchar(250)
SET @a = (SELECT MIN(number) FROM [table])
WHILE (SELECT MAX(number) FROM [table] ) > @a
BEGIN
IF @a NOT IN ( SELECT number FROM [table] )
PRINT @a
SET @a=@a+1
END
```

This will give you the missing numbers....2,3,4,7,8

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(registration_no INT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1),(5),(6),(9)
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT MIN(registration_no) MinVal
      ,MAX(registration_no) MaxVal
FROM @TABLE
)
,
RequiredVals
AS
(
 SELECT DISTINCT [number]
 FROM master..spt_values
 WHERE number >= (SELECT MinVal FROM CTE)
   AND number <= (SELECT MaxVal FROM CTE)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM @TABLE
                   WHERE registration_no = spt_values.number)
)
SELECT number AS MissingValues
FROM RequiredVals
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══════════════╗
║ MissingValues ║
╠═══════════════╣
║             2 ║
║             3 ║
║             4 ║
║             7 ║
║             8 ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
DECLARE @MinVal int 
DECLARE @MaxVal int
SELECT @MinVal=Min(registration_no),@MaxVal=Max(registration_no) FROM TableName
;WITH nums AS
   (SELECT @MinVal AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value + 1 AS value
    FROM nums
    WHERE nums.value <@MaxVal)
SELECT *
FROM nums  
WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT registration_no FROM TableName)
```

Result:

```
VALUE
2
3
4
7
8
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acc63/1).

Comment: Thanks Raging Bull. This was a helpful solution.

Comment: @Konzy262: Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied so that it will help others to find the solution in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a numbers table in regular SQL I believe. The idea is you have a table with a column that just lists all integers. Then you join to that table to find the missing numbers. Basically a poor mans sequence.

```
CREATE TABLE `Numbers` (
  `NUM` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NUM`)
) ;
```

Fill the table with integers.

```
SELECT NUM
FROM
    (SELECT MIN(Registration_no) AS MIN_Range, Max(Registration_no) AS Max_Range
        FROM StackOverflow.Registration) r_temp
INNER JOIN 
    StackOverflow.Numbers n
ON 
    n.NUM >= r_temp.MIN_Range AND n.NUM <= r_temp.MAX_Range
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    StackOverflow.Registration r
ON 
    r.Registration_no = n.NUM
WHERE r.Registration_no IS NULL
;
```

*http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Answer (score 0):

Just Update the "Range" Below (note: code will only work up to the size of sys.columns table)

```
            /* TABLE OF VALUES */
            CREATE TABLE [#table](number varchar(250))
            INSERT INTO [#table] 
            SELECT 1 UNION
            SELECT 5 UNION
            SELECT 6 UNION
            SELECT 9 

            select * from
            (
                select row=row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name) from sys.columns
            )a
            where row BETWEEN 1 and 20 /*CHANGE THIS RANGE*/
            and row not in
            (
                SELECT number FROM [#table] /* TABLE OF VALUES */
            )

            DROP TABLE [#table]
```